# Timemap and mapstraction geocode

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I am having trouble calling the remote action and transforming the JSON data into the data format needed by Timemap.

- What should be the type value for the dataset: "remote" or "jsonp"?
- What is the callback in the remote URL?  Is it required?
- In the transform method, the data I have has only address (no lat lon values), how do I convert this address to lat lon values?  Is there an example with mapstraction? I do not want to create another map with mapstraction or google v3 map?

CODE SNIPPET:

```
tm = TimeMap.init({
        mapId: "map",               // Id of map div element (required)
        timelineId: "timeline",     // Id of timeline div element (required) 
        datasets: [
            {
                id: "fdmdata",
                title: "FDM Data",
                theme: "green",
                type: "remote", // or is it type: "jsonp"
                options: {    
                    //query: fdmMapQuery,
                    url: "loadFdmMapData.ge?" +
                    "orderby=starttime&sortorder=ascending&callback=?",
                    preloadFunction: preloadData,                        
                    transformFunction: transformData,
                }
            },
        ],
        bandInfo: [    
            {
                     width:          "85%", 
                     intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.MONTH, 
                     intervalPixels: 200,
                     theme:          theme
            },
            {
                     width:          "15%", 
                     intervalUnit:   Timeline.DateTime.DAY, 
                     intervalPixels: 300,
                     overview:       true
            }
        ]
    });
});


function transformData(data) {      
    var title, description, start, end, lat, lon, infoHtml;
    var newData = {
        "title" : title,
        "start" : start,
        "end" : end,
        "options" : {
            "description" : description
        }
    };
    newData["point"] = {
       "lat" : lat,
        "lon" : lon
    };            
    newData["options"]["infoHtml"] = infoHtml;
    return newData;
}

function preloadData(result) {
    var entries = (result.feed.entry);
    var events = [];
    // delete events without geotags
    for (var x=0; x<entries.length; x++) {
        entry = entries[x];
        var location = entry['gd$where'][0].valueString;
        var pattern = new RegExp(/@\s*([\-0-9.]+)\s*,\s*([\-0-9.]+)\s*/);
        var matches = pattern.exec(location);
        if (matches != null) events.push(entry);
    }
    return events;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but:

- You probably want loader `type: "jsonp"` or `type: "json"`. `"remote"` is the abstract base for all asynchronous loaders. If you're just loading local JSON, not loading from a JSONP-enabled server, use `"json"`.
- The callback in the remote URL is a part of the way JSONP works. See the `dataType` parameter for [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more info. The callback name will be automatically generated by Timemap.js (using jQuery) - you don't need to worry about the callback function, but you do need to include the parameter in the URL *if* you're using JSONP.
- Transforming an address string to lat/lon is called geocoding, and is not something built into Timemap.js. Generally you'll need to pre-process your data to geocode addresses before loading the data into Timemap - there are various online tools and APIs that can do this for you. [See related questions on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=geocoding%20tools)